# Fast way to mockup hierarchical data easily

Tags: neo4j, mocking, hierarchical-data, data-generation

I'm seeking a quick and easy solution to help mock/populate/test an org chart (in ASP MVC), with tree based or hierarchical data. I need the test data for this...

I have used both http://www.generatedata.com and mock-aro (both of which I like, but the MS Sql data from the site doesn't work, it has multiple syntax errors, including issues with dates an date based data) and looked at redgate - which is not affordable, plus it never got the data right on the nested side.

> **What is the fastest/least effort way/tool to mockup hierarchy data** *like an org chart, with dept, name, cost and employees*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an online tool capable of generating graphs : http://graphgen.graphaware.com

It is based on the Cypher spec.

A simple pattern expressing Deptartment Org Chart, could be defined like this :

```
(Dept1:Department {name:word}*5)<-[:PART_OF *1..n]-(subDept1:Department {name:word} *10)
(Dept2:Department {name:word} *5)<-[:PART_OF *1..n]-(subDept2:Department {name:word} *10)
(ssd1:Department {name:word} *20)-[:PART_OF *n..1]->(subDept1)
(ssd2:Department {name:word} *20)-[:PART_OF *n..1]->(subDept2)
(employee1:Person {name:fullName} *50)-[:WORKS_IN_DEPT *n..1]->(ssd1)
(employee2:Person {name:fullName} *50)-[:WORKS_IN_DEPT *n..1]->(ssd2)
```

You can have a graph preview here : (click on generate after the page is loaded ) http://graphgen.graphaware.com/?graph=koWvmnBTW7JMR7

Also, there is the possibility to import the graph data in your database (even your local db) , create a neo4j console or get a graphjson format.

Don't hesitate to adapt to your needs and try the tool, the documentation is available here : http://graphgen.graphaware.com/documentation

Also, you can ping me on twitter : https://twitter.com/ikwattro for further questions regarding graphgen.

Chris

Comment: I edited the pattern and the link to have a graph with employees ;-)

Comment: 1) Way better than redgate and free!! The tool is awesome, but the syntax is very new to me. I see the query, and the node, but how can I that data into a MS SQL. 2) I was following your comment,  _"also, there is the possibility to import the graph data in your database (even your local db) "_ but **cant figure out where to export to any sql..** or convert the cipher/graphjson to Sql   3) I was thinking about ArangoDb but I may just migrate to Neo4j! one step at a time for now :)

Comment: Thanks. Yes for the import to MSSQL, you'll have to deal with you own transformation of graphjson to mssql, I do not thing such a feature will be added to graphgen as it is dedicated to the neo4j graph database. I talked about graphgen because of the "neo4j" tag of your question. Of course, I can only recommend you to adopt Neo4j :) :) :) .

Comment: However, if you like the application, we can maybe work on a quick proof of concept together, that would transform the graphjson to mssql and writing a blog post about it. feel free to ping me on twitter if you would be interested. Btw we generally do inverse processes, mssql to neo4j :)

Comment: we really want to.., but being a .Net heavy shop and neo being Java, we don't have any resources capable of migrating our data into Neo4J - learning/data migration/and entities was hard to understand. I saw the Neo4J drivers, but no samples. Especially for a dual natured application, where we have **1)** `both hierarchies/graphs and transactional data` **2)** We're also very afraid/concerned of the `licensing costs, we're very small and looking to do some development` is neo flexible, _will they give us time till we get stable?_

Comment: yes, we will connect with you, proof of concept would be great 1) do you have entities, what will our data platform for the app look like with Neo?

Comment: Neo4j could be accessed through an http transactional endpoint, and there is of course a .net driver for it. https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient . Concerning the licensing, if you're a startup, I'm sure you can get some nice advantages for the license pricing depending of the company size and revenues, if you're not a startup, yes then licensing applies, you should then better contact local sales people.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64662/discussion-between-christophe-willemsen-and-aggie).

Comment: soo...what happened to graphgen?